# Angular doesn't show anything anymore after adding new component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, components

I have been building an one-page Angular app the past days, so I used `AppComponent` for my HTML and Typescript because I only have one page. I found out that I needed another page, and I needed routing. To use this, you need to add the `<router-outlet>` component to your `app.component.html`. This was full of HTML code, so I decided to generate a new `MainScreenComponent`. As stupid as I am, I copied ALL the HTML and Typescript code (including class names etc.) and my application didn't work anymore. I couldn't redo this, so I had to figure it out myself. I tried my best, but for now my application still isn't working and I can't find the mistake(s) I have made. This is my code:

HTML of `MainScreenComponent`

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-primary">
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <img id="image" src="favicon.ico">
    <span class="navbar-text">
      <h3>HetWeerInNederland.nl</h3>
    </span>
    </div>
    </nav>


    <div class="input-group mb-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Location" id="locationInput"  aria- label="Recipient's username" aria-describedby="button-addon2">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" type="button" id="button-addon2" 
     (click)="getCoordinates()">Search</button>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <div>
    <h2 id="subtitle">The weather for:  {{this.location}}</h2>
    </div>



     <div class="card-group" [hidden]="hidden">

     <!--  Card 1-->
     <div class="card">
     <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{this.sevenDayForecast.day0}}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{this.sevenDayForecast.date0}}</h6>

      <div class="imageAndTemperature">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{this.sevenDayForecast.icon0}}@2x.png">
        <h4>{{this.sevenDayForecast.daily_temp0}}&#8451;</h4>
      </div>
      <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">{{this.sevenDayForecast.weather_description0}} 
      </h4>


      <div class="humidityAndWindSpeed">
        <div>
          <label style="color:grey;">Humidity</label>
          <p>{{this.sevenDayForecast.humidity0}}%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="windspeed">
          <label style="color: grey">Wind speed</label>
          <p style="color: black">{{this.sevenDayForecast.wind_speed0}} m/s</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a routerLink="/day0" class="stretched-link"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  Card 1-->

           <!--  Card 2-->
           <div class="card">
           <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{this.sevenDayForecast.day1}}</h5>
          <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{this.sevenDayForecast.date1}}</h6>

      <div class="imageAndTemperature">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{this.sevenDayForecast.icon1}}@2x.png">
        <h4>{{this.sevenDayForecast.daily_temp1}}&#8451;</h4>
      </div>
      <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">{{this.sevenDayForecast.weather_description1}} 
      </h4>


      <div class="humidityAndWindSpeed">
        <div>
          <label style="color:grey;">Humidity</label>
          <p>{{this.sevenDayForecast.humidity1}}%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="windspeed">
          <label style="color: grey">Wind speed</label>
          <p style="color: black">{{this.sevenDayForecast.wind_speed1}} m/s</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  Card 2-->

  <!--  Card 3-->
      <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <h5 class="card-title">{{this.sevenDayForecast.day2}}</h5>
        <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{this.sevenDayForecast.date2}}</h6>

      <div class="imageAndTemperature">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{this.sevenDayForecast.icon2}}@2x.png">
        <h4>{{this.sevenDayForecast.daily_temp2}}&#8451;</h4>
      </div>
      <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">{{this.sevenDayForecast.weather_description2}}</h4>


      <div class="humidityAndWindSpeed">
        <div>
          <label style="color:grey;">Humidity</label>
          <p>{{this.sevenDayForecast.humidity2}}%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="windspeed">
          <label style="color: grey">Wind speed</label>
          <p style="color: black">{{this.sevenDayForecast.wind_speed2}} m/s</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <!--  Card 3-->

      <!--  Card 4-->
     <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">{{this.sevenDayForecast.day3}}</h5>
      <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">{{this.sevenDayForecast.date3}}</h6>

      <div class="imageAndTemperature">
        <img src="http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/{{this.sevenDayForecast.icon3}}@2x.png">
        <h4>{{this.sevenDayForecast.daily_temp3}}&#8451;</h4>
      </div>
      <h4 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 0">{{this.sevenDayForecast.weather_description3}}</h4>


      <div class="humidityAndWindSpeed">
        <div>
          <label style="color:grey;">Humidity</label>
          <p>{{this.sevenDayForecast.humidity3}}%</p>
        </div>
        <div class="windspeed">
          <label style="color: grey">Wind speed</label>
          <p style="color: black">{{this.sevenDayForecast.wind_speed3}} m/s</p>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

  <!--  Card 4-->
</div>

      <div>
     <h2>Hello</h2>
      </div>
```

Typescript of `MainScreenComponent`

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {WeatherServiceService} from "../Services/weather-service.service";
import {LocationData} from "../models/location-data";
import {HttpClient} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable} from "rxjs";
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {sevenDayForecast} from "../models/7day-forecast";

  declare const L: any
  @Component({
  selector: 'app-main-screen',
  templateUrl: './main-screen.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./main-screen.component.css']
  })
  export class MainScreenComponent implements OnInit{

  buttonClicks: number =0;
  data!:LocationData
  //lat!:number
  //lon!:number
  hidden: boolean = true;
  location!: string
  locationData = new LocationData();
  sevenDayForecast = new sevenDayForecast();
  constructor(public weatherService:WeatherServiceService, public http: HttpClient) {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    if (!navigator.geolocation){
      console.log("location is not supported")
    }
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const coords = position.coords
      const latLong = [coords.latitude, coords.longitude]
      console.log(
        'lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, lon: ${position.coords.longitude}'
      );
      let mymap = L.map('map').setView(latLong, 13);

      L.tileLayer('https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/{id}/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}?access_token=pk.eyJ1Ijoia29lbnRlcmhlZWdkZSIsImEiOiJja3NpejZibWsxcGFhMzBvZjRlOXhkcWZoIn0.Bs552hPcijlBy1b2kDqfvw', {
        attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
        maxZoom: 18,
        id: 'mapbox/streets-v11',
        tileSize: 512,
        zoomOffset: -1,
        accessToken: 'your.mapbox.access.token'
      }).addTo(mymap);

      let marker = L.marker(latLong).addTo(mymap);
    });
    this.watchPosition();
  }

  watchPosition(){
    let desLat = 0;
    let desLon = 0;
    let id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {
      console.log(
        'lat: ${position.coords.latitude}, lon: ${position.coords.longitude}'
      );
      if (position.coords.latitude === desLat && position.coords.longitude === desLon){
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(id);
      }
    }, (err) => {
      console.log(err);
    }, {
      enableHighAccuracy: false,
      timeout: 5000,
      maximumAge: 0
    })
  }

  getCoordinates(){
    this.hidden = false
    this.location = (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("locationInput")).value
    this.weatherService.getData(this.location).subscribe((data: LocationData) => {
      this.locationData = data;
      //console.log(this.locationData.lat, this.locationData.lon)
      this.get7DayForecast(this.locationData.lat, this.locationData.lon)
    });
  }

  get7DayForecast(lat:number, lon:number){

    this.weatherService.get7DayForecast(lat, lon).subscribe((data: sevenDayForecast) =>{
      this.sevenDayForecast = data;
      console.log(this.sevenDayForecast.daily_temp0)
      //this.sevenDayForecast.day0 = new 
    Date(this.sevenDayForecast.daily_time0*1000).toLocaleDateString("en-US", { weekday: 'long'})
    });
    }
   }
```

HTML of `AppComponent`

```
<app-main-screen></app-main-screen>
```

Typescript of `AppComponent`

```
     import {Component, OnInit} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Typescript of `AppModule`

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Day0Component } from './day0/day0.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { MainScreenComponent } from './main-screen/main-screen.component';
import { Day2Component } from './day2/day2.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Day0Component,
    MainScreenComponent,
    Day2Component
  ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      AppRoutingModule,
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Routing Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";
import {Day0Component} from "./day0/day0.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'day0', component: Day0Component }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})


export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Don't forget ``` <router-outlet></router-outlet> ``` in your app.component.html

Comment: @Mulholland doesn't make a difference unfortunately